# Is it possible to load image in byte array in javascript

Tags: javascript, webos

is it possible to load an image in byte array in javascript instead of loading it to canvas?
I want to make an image editor in javascript webOS but I can't use toDataURl method of HTML 5 canvas because webOs don't support it ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript can only handle printable characters, so some binary values are invalid in Javascript.  That being said, there are ways to encode or pack binary data using base64 or unicode.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is a simple solution.